# Tornado - Replace original data retrieved from mongodb

Tags: mongodb, tornado, database

There's some data stored in `mongodb`, and retrieved into variable `student` with `student = coll.find_one({"name":"Cammy"})`:

`{ "_id" : ObjectId("511367bebb8027582a953cce"), "name" : "Cammy", "desc" : "does well in Math" }`

I want to change some properties of `student` and executed: `student['desc'] = "does well in Physics"`. In order to replace the original document, I used `coll.save(student)`. But instead of replacing, a new record with the same `name` and `desc` but a different `_id` appeared.
  What should I do to replace the original document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
use 

db.coll.findAndModify( {
       query: { name: "cami"},
       update: { $set: { desc: 'does well in physics' } }
} );
```